# Remove white bar things from my dropdown box / how to replace an empty div tag in an boolen queary?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

What is this white stuff around my "open" drown down menu and how do I get rid of it?

I am using DropdownButton from react bootstrap

I already have tried to change the css

```
.Navigation-Bar-Dropdown-Container{
    color: $NormalFontColour ;
    background-color: $TopBarBackgroundColour;
    border:none;

}
```

[image]

[image]

On a side question I also have the following code:

```
{values.map((newItem) => ( 
       <div key={newItem.id}> 
          {newItem.parentId == item.id? <a className="Navigation-Bar-Sub-Menu-Items-Container" href="#">
               <div className="Sub-Menu-Sub-Menu-Titles">{newItem.title}</div>
               <div className="Sub-Menu-Sub-Menu-Shortcuts">{newItem.shortcutCommand}</div>
            </a>:<div></div>}
```

is there something I can replace "`:<div></div>`" with? As it results in loads of empty div tags on my page?

Comment: You can just return null, or [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) without content. `</a> : null}`

Comment: Ah thanks I tried none instead...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background of the parent div to be the same as your child div, i.e.

```
 <div key={newItem.id} className="Navigation-Bar-Dropdown-Container"> .... </div>
```

Comment: I already tried that unfortunately and didnt work when I went through the console i saw this .dropdown-menu {
--bs-dropdown-bg: #fff;
} when i deselected it that seemed to be the problem but I am not sure how to do this is css

Comment: you can try right click inspect in browser and see what element it is, and then put a css on that element, or add css to that

Comment: If I use .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: $TopBarBackgroundColour!important;
} it "fixes" the problem. However, Is it ok to use to do that?

Comment: yea, the !important is to prioritize this style  or u can create a new class for it and set it as important, btw, if you are react developer, try look into tailwindcss, it will solve a lot of your css problem